# How use Eclipse as a Javascript IDE?

Tags: javascript, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, rte, jsdt

I downloaded the eclipse Javascript IDE from the official download page however, when i start the application it says "A Java Runtime Environment or Java development Kit must be available in order to run eclipse." I already have a java IDE copy of eclipse that runs fine so I don't understand why its asking for another JDK.

I just want to develop Javascript in Eclipse, does anyone have any idea how to? Are there special tools or plugins i'm meant to get to get it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For best experience doing JS/HTML/CSS I recommend you using Aptana as plugin. Here you can download it http://www.aptana.com/products/studio3/download Be sure to check *Eclipse Plug-in Version* option.

Comment: I am using Aptana plugin but it still feels inferior to the way Eclipse understands Java code. When I code a Java object, Eclipse uses auto-fill support to give me a list of methods and descriptions for each. No such thing happens when using JavaScript with eclipse. When you have a potential resource leak in Java or you want to know what kind of exceptions a method throws, all this is built into Eclipse for Java. However, all I get with Aptana with JavaScript is syntax highlighting. It feels inferior.

Answer (score 5):

Maybe other copy of eclipse use -vm variable in eclipse.ini file, therefore, it work correctly.
Make sure you have JAVA_HOME in Environment Variables or add -vm configuration into eclipse.ini file.

For more information, see this link:
http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_run_Eclipse%3F

Answer (score 0):

Check your version of the runtime that you installed. You can upgrade or downgrade (i.e. if JDK 7, then try JDK 8 and vice versa you can even try JDK 6) and see if it works.

On Ubuntu 14.10 open JDK 7 did not help me much but the older (open JDK java 6 runtime) and the newer open JDK Java 8 helped me out.